# Java equivalent of Perl's s/// operator?

Tags: java, regex, perl

I have some code that I'm converting from Perl to Java.  It makes pretty heavy use of regular expressions, including the `s///` operator.  I've been using Perl for a long time and am still getting used to the Java way of doing things.  In particular, Strings seem more difficult to work with.  Does anyone know of or have a Java function that fully implements `s///`?  So that it could handle something like this, for example:

```
$newString =~ s/(\bi'?\b)/\U$1/g;
```

(Maybe not a great example, but you get the idea.)  Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the Jakarta ORO regexp library, for \U support see the http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/api/org/apache/oro/text/regex/Perl5Substitution.html class

Comment: After looking into it a little bit, ORO is indeed very useful.  Having s/// and a built-in \U operator is great.  So far, I recommend it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at String's [replaceAll(...)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method. Note that Java does not support the `\U` (upper-case) feature.

Comment: Thanks.  I've also found Matcher.replaceAll().  Are they powerful enough to handle my example of upcasing the match, though...?

Comment: `Matcher.replaceAll()` is used by `String`'s `replaceAll()`. So that answers your other question: no, `\U` is not supported.

Comment: I missed the \U part of your reply.  I guess I have to accept that replaceAll() will work for most but not all cases.

Comment: To emphasize: not only `replaceAll(...)` does not support it, but the entire Java regex package doesn't.

Comment: Thanks again, Bart (and to everyone else, too; my first question here!).

Answer (score 6):

Nothing so tidy, but in Java you would use [String.replaceAll()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) or use [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to do something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\bi'?\b)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToReplace);
m.replaceAll("$1");
```

Check the Pattern docs for Java's regex syntax--it doesn't overlap completely with Perl.

---

To get uppercasing, check out [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    String uppercaseGroup = m.group(1).toUpperCase();
    m.appendReplacement(sb, uppercaseGroup);
}
m.appendTail();
```

Not as close to Perl as the jakarta-oro library referenced above, but definitely some help built into the library.

Answer (score 1):

Given an instance of a String class you can use the .replaceAll() method like so:

```
String A = "Test";
A.replaceAll("(\bi'?\b)","\U$1");
```

Edit - ok too slow. Also apparently \U isn't supported according to another answer.

Note - I'm not sure how the greedy symbol translates, you might want to try looking into Java's implementation if you need that specifically.

Comment: The `\U` in your replacement string will cause a RuntimeException to be thrown.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been pretty impressed at how much the regexp syntax is identical, aside from extra backslashing in Java.  (Too bad about \U, though.)  I wish Java's string handling was more like Perl's....

Comment: As it comes to string manipulation, Perl is king. But yes, Java's regex implementation is a solid and powerful one, albeit verbose at times with all the backslashes and object creation.

Comment: \U isn't really regexp syntax in perl, it's double-quoted string syntax.