# parse text file in java, how to remove ""

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have a simple java code that reads text csv file that contains sentences with double quotations: "sentence1","sentence2","sentence3". I want to read some of these sentences(e.g, sentence 1 and 3). I created a buffer reader and used `readLine()` then used: `tokens = fileLine.split(",");` where tokens is an array of strings.

I accessed the sentences I'm interested in using the array index as: `tokens[0]`, `tokens[3]`. The problem is that, I want the sentences only without the double quotations. But my program saved the sentences with "". How can I improve the parsing technique so I can save the sentences without "" ??

Comment: Use a csv parser (there are plenty, including open source solutions) - it will make your life easier (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200609/can-you-recommend-a-java-library-for-reading-and-possibly-writing-csv-files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
theSentence = theSentence.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

In newer Java versions, I think from Java 5, you can use [`String#replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) as well:

```
theSentence = theSentence.replace("\"", "");
```

And avoid the overhead of regex

Comment: I *think* theSentence.replace("\"", ""); works as well.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @BlackVegetable - you're right, I just edited the answer, but this is not available in older Java versions.

Answer (score 0):

see 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29
and related question [Java equivalent of Perl's s/// operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254921/java-equivalent-of-perls-s-operator)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
tokens = s.split("\",\"");
```

Please note that your implementation parses input line 
`"Hello, world","second sentence"`
as the array

```
"Hello
world"
"second sentence"
```

The above code works only if your lines do not contain (escaped) quotes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the method `String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)`.

For example:

```
String s = "hello world";
s = s.replaceAll("o","X");
//s now equals "hellX wXrld"
```

In your case you would want your regex to be: "\""
And your replacement to be: ""

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove just `"` from beginning and end of string you can do it also this way:

```
String sentence="\"my sentence\"";
System.out.println(sentence);//out->"my sentence"

sentence = sentence.substring(1,sentence.length()-1);   
System.out.println(sentence);//out->my sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more of an interesting solution than anything, rather than splitting right away, why not do this?

```
String inputFromCSV; // This would have the value of what you read from the CSV.
inputFromCSV=inputFromCSV.substring(1,sentence.length()-1); 
String[] tokens = inputFromCSV.split("\",\""); // Essentially ","
```

Actually looking at it, it's not that bad, and will work so long as your file keeps the same format.